# why js code separate the divisions?

Tags: javascript, css, progress-bar

In the following code, the js code is supposed to give an animated load to the progress bar. But, don't know why the yellow bar is displaced and is not placed right on

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  }
});

bar.animate(1.0); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#liner {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>
<div id="liner">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: One issue is that `container` in this line: `var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, ...` should be `'#container'` as a string and referencing the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the css property `position: absolute;` in your svg.

---

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/cr47qa99/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute'
  }
});

bar.animate(1.0); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
```

```css
#liner {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/progressbar.js/1.0.1/progressbar.min.js"></script>
<div id="liner">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```